автодобавление бб кода через js
как можно в js прописать, чтобы при выборе селект в поле message добавилось автоматически так: [b]★★★★★[/b]
<select id="Rating" onchange="myFunction()">
     <option>შეფასება</option>
     <option>★★★★★</option> 
     <option>★★★★</option> 
     <option>★★★</option>
     <option>★★</option>
     <option>★</option>
     </select>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
     var mylist = document.getElementById("Rating");
     document.getElementById("message").value = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
    }
    </script>


Ну прям вот так и напишите. Вы же сейчас текст выводите вот перед ним и после добавьте '[b]'. Склеивание строк идет через +


как можно в js прописать, чтобы при выборе селект в поле message добавилось автоматически так: [b]★★★★★[/b]

Например вот так...


function myFunction() {
  const mylist = document.getElementById("Rating");
  document.getElementById("message").value = `[b]${mylist.value}[/b]`
}
<select id="Rating" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option>შეფასება</option>
  <option>★★★★★</option>
  <option>★★★★</option>
  <option>★★★</option>
  <option>★★</option>
  <option>★</option>
</select>
<input id='message' />



